# How to prevent form hacking in client-side code

Tags: javascript, vue.js, security, client-side

This is a general question more than a specific problem I have with code. The question came up discussing the pros & cons of using frameworks such as VueJS and performing say form validation on the client vs. submitting the data to the server where a controller does the data validation.

His argument was that since the code (i.e JS code) and the data reside on the client there is always the possibility of someone tampering with the data/code then submitting the data to the server therefor bypassing validation. I'm new to VueJS coming to it from PHP + CodeIgniter and would like to hear your thoughts on the subject.

How valid is this argument?

thank you,

Comment: _"How valid is this argument?"_ Extremely valid. [StackOverflow is not a discussion forum](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Wow! thank you all for the prompt response. Ok, 3 comments: 1) the question was not specific to passwords, 2) ignoring for a second the case of forgetting to implement validation on the server, wouldn't you want to implement ALL validations on the server rather than in two places? 3) what is the best way to implement server side validation (assuming it's a VueJS SPA) with a Firebase backend? I'm looking for best practices here for a commercial public application. thanks again.

Comment: @Phil, I understand this is not a discussion forum however and with all due respect, I think the topic is a valid coding question.

Comment: If you had a specific question it would be but right now, you're asking for opinions which are off-topic

Comment: It does not just apply to password but honestly any form fields. Also wouldnt you want to implement ALL validation on server rather than in 2 places? No. By having client side validation you improve user experience, reduce delay, reduce unnecessary bottlenecks and network traffics because not everybody is going to switch off js or intercept packets for fun. However i do agree that server side validation is more important and should be prioritized during development. But don't do away with client side validation either. Less important doesn't mean not important.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, a malicious user can tamper with client-side code and remove all the security and validation checks. Trying to stop them is a waste of time and effort. Instead, move all such checks out of the client-side code and into your server-side code.

Comment: Nothing wrong with having both client-side and server-side validation

Comment: @Phil I'd say there's a tiny bit wrong with it: if you forget a server-side validation check, your testers probably won't notice if there is such a check on the client.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica that wasn't the argument. Notice the word "both"

Comment: @A.Lau My point is, if your policy is to have both, and you forget the server-side one, you might not notice in testing, but if your policy is to have just the server-side one, and you forget it, you're much more likely to notice in testing.

Comment: your argument literally makes no sense. Tests aren't exclusively for server or client. You can write tests for both. Writing client side validation is to ensure that users don't submit a form then get a "rejected" error because required or specifically formatted aren't set properly. It's like if you could type letters or more than 16 digits into a credit card field. Client side isn't security, it's convenience.

Answer (score 1):

How Valid? Very Valid.

Client side validation are extremely easy to bypass. Which is why you need to check the inputs even at the server side.

That being said client side validation are still useful for a number of reasons. For instance if your password has to be alphanumeric you want to check that at the client side first. Its not fun having bottlenecks in your server just because your password requirement is too hard to reach. In essence without your client side validation, every time somebody enters a less than strong password it goes to your server then comes back which is a delay and unnecessary network traffic.

That being said you should still validate if they are alphanumeric at the server side.